# Android replace links in clipboard with expanded URL

Tags: android, android-edittext, clipboard

I'm using a normal EditText which accepts input. When a user pastes text with linked content copied from an textView with URLSpans, the link is gone.

eg. Here is a [Link](http://google.com)

I want this to be pasted as

Here is a http://google.com

Comment: What is your input, can you give some explanation?

Comment: The input is mentioned in the question. Its some HTML i copy which has an anchor tag <a href="URL">LABEL</a>. Instead of anchor tag, I want it to be replaced by LABEL

Comment: That means you want html tags should be removed. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

please try this:

```
android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.content.ClipboardManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                    android.content.ClipData.Item item = clipboard.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0);
                    String pasteData = item.getText().toString();
                    if (pasteData != null) {
                       EditText.setText(pasteData);
```